# Programmatically sending SMS from desktop application when connected to Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sms, desktop-application

I want to create a desktop application from where  I can send SMS when windows phone 8 is connected to desktop. Is it possible? If so, how can I achieve that? What APIs I need to use?

Comment: If the connected phone have inbuilt modem you can do that using `AT Command`. [See an example here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com)

Comment: If you edited the question to include details of why you're trying to do that, there might be another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send an SMS completely programmatically in Windows Phone. In order to get somewhere close to that, you can use the [SMS Compose Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to show a new page with a message already entered.

Also, I cannot be completely sure here, but I don't think that a WP application can connect with a computer through USB. The APIs are usually quite restricting for the developer on WP.